# How to create a Blob from a local file in phonegap on android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview, blob

I am trying to upload a file to amazon S3 from a phonegap app on android. I already have the code working for iOS. But I've got a trouble making it work on android. The problem is that I do not know how to create the `Blob` object properly. On iOS I just do this:

```
blob = new Blob([evt.target.result], {type: "image/png"});
```

It is uploaded just fine. On android one can not use the `Blob` constructor (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/YqRNh82d1K0)), but I could not manage to get the file data correctly into the `Blob` object using `WebKitBlobBuilder`.

Here is how I retrieve the file data, there are two approaches and both pass without errors, but the resulting file on the S3 is **empty**:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(url, function(e){
    e.file(function(f){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        // This way also did not work:
        //    var builder = new WebKitBlobBuilder();
        //    builder.append(evt.target.result);
        //    blob = builder.getBlob("image/png");

            var blob = null;
            var builder = new WebKitBlobBuilder();
            for(var i = 0; i < evt.target.result.length; i++){
                builder.append(evt.target.result[i]);
            }
            blob = builder.getBlob("image/png");
            uploadToS3(filename, s3url, blob);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    });
}, function(e){
    console.log("error getting file");
    error();
});
```

also, here is the uploadToS3 function:

```
var uploadToS3 = function(filename, s3url, fileData) {
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('PUT', s3url);
    if(!xhr) {
        console.log('CORS not supported');
        error();
        return;
    }
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if(xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log('100% - Upload completed.');
            callback(filename); //callback defined in outer context
        }
        else {
            console.log('0% - Upload error: ' + xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            error();
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        console.log(0, 'XHR error.');
        error();
    };
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        if(e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentLoaded = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            var label = (percentLoaded == 100) ? 'Finalizing.' : 'Uploading.';
            console.log(percentLoaded + "% - " + label);
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "image/png");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
    xhr.send(fileData);
};
```

**EDIT**:
I checked the filesize by logging `evt.target.result.byteLength` and it was ok, so `evt.target.result` contains image data. Still there is a problem with the upload - I checked the s3 storage and file size is 0, so I am not constructing the `Blob` correctly.

Comment: use blobuilder to act like new Blob...

Comment: If I try to upload `WebKitBlobBuilder` object itself, a text file with contents `[object WebKitBlobBuilder]` is uploaded. Expected, as it is a builder, not the data itself.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet?  I think that you need to use the BlobBuilder and then call builder.getBlob().  I'm still having this issue though, can't find an API that actually works on my 4.1.2 target...

Comment: I have found a workaround, and added an answer to this question explaining what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is an android bug after all, which was not fixed since at least Nov 2012.

Here is an article I found which is directly related to my problem: https://ghinda.net/article/jpeg-blob-ajax-android/

It also provides a workaround for the bug, which is to send `ArrayBuffer` directly, without creating a `Blob`. In my case I had to send `evt.target.result` directly.

Comment: Do you have any insights as to memory consumption with this method? Would the entire file be read into memory at any point in time (I'm a bit unfamiliar with how `Blob` works internally, particularly in conjunction with XMLHTTPRequest and FormData)?

Comment: Well, if you read the file with `readAsArrayBuffer` it is obviously copied to memory, so memory consumption should be at least equal to the target file size. As for the internal operation of XMLHTTPRequest, frankly I have no idea whether it has any overhead.

Comment: @Perfection Sorry about that, this is not my blog, just an article I found while searching for the solution. Probably the author thought this problem is no longer relevant =) BTW, I have provided the workaround from the article in the answer.